# In a `facet_wrap`ed grid, center subplots at 0 while keeping `free_x`

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the plot below, I have a faceted grid.

Is there any way to center both subplots at `0`, while keeping different `min`/`max` values for the `x` axis?

In the case below that would be `xlim=c(-1,1)` for left and `xlim=c(-2,2)` for right, but it should be generally applicable.

(in a real life example, those are faceted volcano plots and I want to center at `0` effect size but keep the different `x` scales for different plots)

```
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(x=c(1,2), y=c(0,0), group=c(1,2))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~group, scale="free_x")
```

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've also needed something like this to display asymmetric spectra side-by-side,

[image]

Try this function,

```
symmetrise_scale <- function(p, axis = "x"){
  gb <- ggplot_build(p)
  type <- switch(axis, "x" = "x.range", "y" = "y.range")
  lims <- sapply(gb$panel$ranges, "[[", type)
  fname <- as.character(p$facet$facets)
  facets <- gb$panel$layout[[fname]]
  lims2 <- as.vector(t(tcrossprod(apply(abs(lims), 2, max), c(-1,1))))
  dummy <- setNames(data.frame(rep(facets, each=2), lims2), c(fname, axis))
  switch(axis, 
         "x" = p + geom_blank(data=dummy, aes(x=x, y=Inf), inherit.aes = FALSE), 
         "y" = p + geom_blank(data=dummy, aes(x=Inf, y=y), inherit.aes = FALSE))
}


library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(x=c(1,2), y=c(5,0.2), group=c(1,2))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~group, scale="free")
symmetrise_scale(p, "x")
```

[image]

```
symmetrise_scale(p, "y")
```

[image]

Comment: The function fails when additional aesthetics are added to global aesthetics in the p plot. For instance:   `df = data.frame(x=c(1,2), y=c(5,0.2), group=c(1,2), colour = c("a", "b"));

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour = colour)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~group, scale="free")`  

Perhaps you might consider adding `inherit.aes = FALSE`  to `geom_blank(......`

Comment: (it can probably be broken in a multitude of ways...)

Comment: [tentative version to support multiple facetting variables](https://gist.github.com/baptiste/2cafb70b46428a3b298c6a5078c38284)

Answer (score 4):

A simpler, perhaps more robust solution, would be the following. In a more complex plot using several dataframes you would need a similar `geom_blank` term for each one.

```
df = data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), y=c(5,-3,2,-0.2,0.3,-0.1), group=c(1,1,1,2,2,2))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
      geom_blank(aes(y=-y)) + #plot mirror image points invisibly (can do same with x)
      geom_line() + facet_wrap(~group, scale="free")
```

[image]

Comment: good idea, that would definitely be a good solution for simple plots, but it doesn't extend automatically e.g for plots with multiple layers

Comment: Agreed - although I guess in most cases it would be straightforward to add similar terms for each layer.

Answer (score 3):

with version `ggplot2_2.2.1.9000`

```
symmetrise_scale <- function(p, axis = "x"){
  gb <- ggplot_build(p)
  type <- switch(axis, "x" = "x.range", "y" = "y.range")

  fname <- setdiff(names(gb$layout$layout), c("PANEL", "ROW", "COL",  "SCALE_X", "SCALE_Y"))  
  facets <- gb$layout$layout[ ,fname, drop=FALSE]

  lims <- do.call(cbind, lapply(gb$layout$panel_params, "[[", type))
  lims2 <- as.vector(t(tcrossprod(apply(abs(lims), 2, max), c(-1,1))))

  dummy <- setNames(data.frame(facets[rep(seq_len(nrow(facets)), each=2),], lims2), c(fname, axis))

    switch(axis, 
         "x" = p + geom_blank(data=dummy, aes(x=x, y=Inf), inherit.aes = FALSE), 
         "y" = p + geom_blank(data=dummy, aes(x=Inf, y=y), inherit.aes = FALSE))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(x=c(1,2), y=c(0,0), group=c(1,2))

# determine the maximum range
df_xr <- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(xr = max(abs(x))) %>%
  ungroup()

# join the mximum range ot original df
df_plot <- df %>% 
  inner_join(df_xr)

# plot using geom_blank to force the extents without plotting anything
ggplot(df_plot, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_blank(aes(x = xr)) +
  geom_blank(aes(x = -xr)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~group, scale="free_x")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick - for now (this is `ggplot2 2.2.1`).  The main edits to the previous answer are to reflect changes in the names/structure of the `ggplot_build` object.

```
symmetrise_scale <- function(p, axis = "x"){
  gb <- ggplot_build(p)
  type <- switch(axis, "x" = "x.range", "y" = "y.range")

  fname <- setdiff(names(gb$layout$panel_layout), c("PANEL", "ROW", "COL",  "SCALE_X", "SCALE_Y"))  
  facets <- gb$layout$panel_layout[ ,fname, drop=FALSE]

  lims <- do.call(cbind, lapply(gb$layout$panel_ranges, "[[", type))
  lims2 <- as.vector(t(tcrossprod(apply(abs(lims), 2, max), c(-1,1))))

  dummy <- setNames(data.frame(facets[rep(seq_len(nrow(facets)), each=2),], lims2), c(fname, axis))

  switch(axis, 
         "x" = p + geom_blank(data=dummy, aes(x=x, y=Inf), inherit.aes = FALSE), 
         "y" = p + geom_blank(data=dummy, aes(x=Inf, y=y), inherit.aes = FALSE))
}


library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), y=c(5,-3,2,-0.2,0.3,-0.1), group=c(1,1,1,2,2,2))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~group, scale="free")
symmetrise_scale(p, "y")
```

[image]

Comment: I must have missed something: how's your code different from the one I posted 2 days ago?

Comment: In the three `gb$layout$...` references.  Your answer didn't work for me, so I had a closer look!

Comment: we're probably not running the same version of ggplot2; I have `ggplot2_2.2.1.9000`

Comment: Mine is `2.2.1` according to `sessionInfo`.