# How to set dynamic data limits across facets in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set that I've wrangled in R to list change in visitor numbers in particular locations in 3 different periods: 2019, 2020, 2021. Some of these changes are very big (+/- ~200), but most are small, (+/- ~2).

I need to plot these changes in ggplot2 for a dashboard that I'm building, faceted by location. The code I've written using dummy data for a simple, reproducible example is below:

```
location <- rep(c("1001", "1002", "1003", "1004"), c(3, 3, 3, 3))
period <- rep(c(2019, 2020, 2021), 4)
change <- c(-3.1, 5.4, -2.2, 190.8, 2.3, 150, 0.34, -0.44, -0.67, 1.2, 3, 4)

tot <- data.frame(location, period, change)


ggplot(data = tot, aes(x = period, y = change)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~location, ncol = 1, scales = "free")
```

...which gives me the following graph:

[image: an image of a graph]

Obviously, this is not great to look at. What I would *like* is for 0 to always be in the centre of the graph. I know I can accomplish this by adding

```
+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-200, 200)
```

which encompasses all the data in this example, but that leaves me with the problem of bars in facets where data only ranges between, say -1 and 1, being so tiny they're impossible to distinguish, as you can see, particularly in location 1003:

[image: an image of a graph]

Is there a way to dynamically set limits in facets based on the range of the data in that facet?

Comment: Not to stray away from the question, but this approach seems to violate [proper data visualization approaches](https://xdgov.github.io/data-design-standards/components/axes). Since you are using the same variable, by changing the scales of the x-axis for different settings it may appear that the settings are more similar than they appear. It is standard practice in visual comparisons  that the axes be consistent across all panels. Perhaps look at relative (%) change?

Comment: It is relative change. I accept it might potentially be misleading, but how else can I make the small bars legible?

Comment: If the units here are already expressed in % change (unclear if this is true), then another approach to presenting the results clearly without distorting the perception of the relationships among locations is to separate these into two plots: One with three (fixed-x) panels for locations 1001, 1002, 1004, and a separate plot for 1003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comments, although I think this accomplishes the original goal. [Based on this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635016/in-a-facet-wraped-grid-center-subplots-at-0-while-keeping-free-x)

```
library(tidyverse)

location <- rep(c("1001", "1002", "1003", "1004"), c(3, 3, 3, 3))
period <- rep(c(2019, 2020, 2021), 4)
change <- c(-3.1, 5.4, -2.2, 190.8, 2.3, 150, 0.34, -0.44, -0.67, 1.2, 3, 4)

tot <- data.frame(location, period, change)

ggplot(data = tot, aes(x = period, y = change)) +
  geom_blank(aes(y=-change)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~location, ncol = 1, scales = "free")
```